# SQL query to check if value of one column is greater than other

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

[image]

I would like to select id where value of c2 when c3 = 100 is greater than value of c2 when c3 = 101.

My query should select id 841213874

Comment: The screenshot you've included doesn't have a c3. I assume you mean c4, but for the sake of clarity, you may want to update your screenshot or the wording to use c4

Comment: Also, the ask is not so clear. If you want to compare column values, you can try using a case statement.

Comment: There is no `c3`.

Comment: I have corrected the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having max(case when c3 = 100 then c2 end) > max(case when c3 = 101 then c2 end);
```

You can also use a correlated subquery:

```
select id
from t
where cd = 100 and
      c2 > (select max(t2.c2) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.c3 = 101);
```

Comment: @ushrani . . . Did they work or not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM tablename t1
WHERE t1.c3 = 100
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename t2 WHERE t2.c3 = 101 AND t2.c2 < t1.c2)
```